# How to define dynamic XML tag values in XSL file

Tags: xslt

I have a situation where I am displaying some values (from xml) in a DataGrid.
For that I have a Display.xsl file where I am defining some of the xml tag Values. For Example, "UserType" ("UserType" is the XML Tag and it has to displayed like "User Type='XML tag value'") would be like:

```
<xsl:call-template name="FormatTextData">
    <xsl:with-param name="textValue" select="//UserType"/><!-- xml tag value-->
    <xsl:with-param name="displayValue" select="';User Type='"/><!-- Display Value-->
</xsl:call-template>
```

This is working fine. But the problem is, similarly I need to define a value which is half static half dynamic. The Tag Value is "UserRoleCollection.RoleName", in which "UserRoleCollection." will remain constant but "RoleName" is dynamic in nature, and will change as RoleName1. RoleName2, RoleName3.....etc. I mean no of roles will varry.

```
<xsl:call-template name="FormatTextData">
    <xsl:with-param name="textValue" select="//UserRoleCollection.*"/><!-- xml tag value-->
    <xsl:with-param name="displayValue" select="';User Role Collection.*='"/><!-- Display Value-->
</xsl:call-template>
```

so how to define it in a way so that all the diffrent roles can be served in one shot?

I hope I am clear with my problem. Please suggest some solution for the same.

**To explpain it a little further:**

I need to display a xml Tag, let say:XML tag is "UserName" and the value of the Tag is "Aashu". I have to display it as "User Name=Aashu". 
Similarly in case of Tag "UserRoleCollectio.RoleName" no of values (RoleNames) are not constant (RoleName in tag can be replaced by Painter, Driver, Cook and so on with there respective values as Yes, No, Yes and so on) so I may have to display 2/3/...or more than that roles in GRID. 
While generating XML I have generated it as given "UserRoleCollection.RoleName(after dot it will change for every XML tag as there may be more than one role)".
Now I want to display the same as "User Role Collection.Painter=Yes", User ROle Collection.Driver=No, and like this.............

```
<AUDITDATA>
  <USERS>
    <Domain>DOMAUDIT</Domain>
    <UserName>Aashu</UserName>
    <PassWord>m0eYN2VM</PassWord>
    <Description>1234</Description>
    <UserType>AdminOps</UserType>
    <UserRoleCollection.Painter>YES</UserRoleCollection.Painter>
    <UserRoleCollection.Driver>NO</UserRoleCollection.Driver>
    <UserRoleCollection.Cook>YES</UserRoleCollection.Cook>
    <!-- like this there may be more roles also.-->
  </USERS>
</AUDITDATA>
```

I want to Display it in a DataGrid column as "Domain=DOMAUDIT, User Name=Aashu, Description=1234, User Type=AdminOps, User Role Collection.Painter=YES, User Role Collection.Driver=NO, User Role Collection.Cook=YES....and so on.

For which I have used XSLT file. now the problem is in XML I can get 10/100 roles and there values, so I can't define these many roles in XSL file because I am not sure how many roles I can get at any given time. So as The first part (UserRoleCollection.) of the TAG is common I thought there might be some way to define this in XSL file .....Now please help if there is any solution possible.

Comment: It would probably helped if you showed a sample of your input (with various "RoleNames") along with the output you expect. Thanks!

Comment: Please go through my explaination once...

Comment: I agree with TimC, your explanation is a bit confusing without an example...

Comment: Now I have given more details, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You may use a generic template:

```
<xsl:template match="USERS">
  <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    <xsl:text>='</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Erlock, but still I didn't get how to make it for this section of XML code.
    <UserRoleCollection.Painter>YES</UserRoleCollection.Painter>
    <UserRoleCollection.Driver>NO</UserRoleCollection.Driver>
    <UserRoleCollection.Cook>YES</UserRoleCollection.Cook>